# Python socket client to a Java socket server

Tags: java, python, sockets, client

I have a Java socket server that is expecting exactly `n` bytes from some port. I want to write a Python clients that just sends bytes on some port to the Java server.

Since Python does not have primitives, I'm not sure to send exactly `n` bytes. Any suggestions?

More details:

I have a Java DatagramSocket that takes in `n` bytes:

```
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[n], n);
```

Answer (score 1):

`somesocket.send` takes a byte-string argument `s` -- just ensure that `len(s) == n`, and you **will** be sending exacty `n` bytes.  What do "primitives" have to do with it?!

To turn arbitrary bunches of data into byte strings (and back), see the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module in Python's standard library (for the specific but frequent case of homogeneous arrays of simple types such as floats, the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module is often even better).

Comment: So say I want to send the double 3.4. Java doubles are 64 bits, so I would need to encode a python 3.4 into 8 bytes. How would I do this? I've never really pushed bits around in python so this is rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **datagram** socket (e. g. the UDP protocol over IP), the Socket API guarantees that if your `n` is less than the maximum payload size, then your data will be sent in a single packet. So just calling `socket.send` would be sufficient.

The easiest way to send data over a **stream** socket is to use the `socket.sendall` method, as `send` for streams doesn't guarantee that all the data is actually sent (and you should repeatedly call `send` in order to transmit all the data you have). Here is an example:

```
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 12345))
>>> data = 'your data of length n'
>>> s.sendall(data)
```

As @Alex has already mentioned, there is nothing related to some kind of "primitives" in Python. It is just and issue with the Socket API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers, I figured out what I was looking for. What I wanted was struct.unpack and struct.pack to allow me to pack the python float 1.2345 to a string representation of a C double.

That is:

```
>>> struct.pack('d', 1.2345)
'\x8d\x97n\x12\x83\xc0\xf3?'
>>> struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('d', 1.2345))[0]
1.2344999999999999
```

Thanks!